# Standard deviation of X compared to 1-X, a problem related to utilities and statistical decisions

Tags: standard-deviation, decision-theory, variability

In health economics, a utility $U$ is defined as 1 = perfect health and 0 = death, though it is possible to have utilities $<0$ for conditions worse than death. Theoretically, $U$ is therefore in the interval ($-\infty$, 1], a range can pose issues when model/distribution fitting is required. A common recommendation is that a disutility $D = 1- U$ should be used instead of $U$ for modeling. $D$ is attractive since it is found in the interval $[0, \infty$) and can be modeled with a gamma or lognormal distribution, for example.

My question concerns the variability of $U$ and $D$.  If $U$ has a standard deviation of $\sigma$, what is the standard deviation of $D$?

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. More generally, for constants $a$ and $b$,

$$\text{Var}(aX+b) = a^2 \text{Var}(X)$$

For the standard deviation, this translates into:

$$\text{Std}(aX+b) = |a| \text{Std}(X)$$

On an intuitive level, if you picture the density of $U$, and then flip it from left to right about zero and then translate it, you have not changed the "spread" of the distribution at all, so it shouldn't have a different variance.

```
D <- exp(rnorm(10000, sd = 0.5))
U <- 1 - D
plot(density(U, to = 1), xlim = c(-4, 4), col = "blue", main = "Density")
lines(density(D, from = 0), col = "red")
legend("topleft", legend = c("D", "U"), col = c("red","blue"), lty = 1)
```

[image]